How to Reset Retry Backoff After Successful WebSocket Connection in Spring Flux
I'm using a WebSocket client with Spring Flux and implementing a retry mechanism with exponential backoff. However, I've encountered an issue where the backoff delay continues to increase even after a successful connection. Ideally, I want the retry count and backoff delay to reset to the initial state after each successful connection, but with the current setup, the delay continues to increase until it reaches the maximum backoff duration, regardless of successful connections in between retries.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
RetryBackoffSpec retryConfig = Retry.backoff(Long.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .maxBackoff(Duration.ofHours(1));

ReactorNettyWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();

URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("wss://******").build().toUri();

Mono<Void> connectMono = webSocketClient.execute(uri, new WebSocketHandler() {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketSession session) {
    return session.receive()
                  .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15)) // Timeout to trigger error when the connection is lost
                  .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                  .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                  .then();
  }
});

connectMono.doOnSuccess(unused -> System.out.println("Connection successful"))
           .retryWhen(retryConfig)
           .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> {
                System.out.println("Attempt " + (retrySignal.totalRetries() + 1));                
            })
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                System.out.println("Retries exhausted: " + e.getMessage());
                return Mono.empty();
            });

Problem:
The retry backoff mechanism keeps increasing the delay between retries even after a successful connection, which isn't ideal for WebSocket connections. I want the retries and backoff to reset after each successful connection.
Question:
Is there an elegant solution that allows resetting the retry backoff after a successful WebSocket connection, without manually handling the delay time between retries? The current design seems to be more suitable for scenarios other than WebSocket connections.
Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
